# Formulario modal con jquery-ui en laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, jquery-ui

**tengo un formulario de tipo modal donde pretendo realizar una búsqueda por nombre de empresa y al momento de seleccionar un nombre se autocomplete los demás campos de mi formulario, estoy utilizando el autocomplete de jquery-ui y hasta el momento estoy tratando de realizar la busqueda pero no esta funcionado.**

ruta:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'auth'],   
function(){    
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');     
    Route::resource('orders',       'OrderController', ['as' => 'admin']);  
});

Route::get('orders/table',      'OrderController@dataTable')->name('orders.table'); 
// Route::get('orders/search',     'OrderController@search')->name('orders.search'); 
Route::get('orders/search',     'OrderController@search');
```

controllador OrderController:

aca en el controlador tengo el metodo create donde paso las variables a mi formulario.
Tambien tengo el metodo search donde realizo la busqueda por nombre de empresa

```
public function create()
    {
        $order = new Order();          

        $companies = Client::with('company')->get(); 

        // $company = Company::pluck('name_company', 'id');

        $user = User::pluck('name', 'id');       

        return view('admin.orders.partials.form', compact('order', 'user', 'companies'));
    }

public function search(Request $request)
    {   

        $search = $request->term;

        $orders = Company::where('name_company', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $data = [];

        foreach($orders as $key => $value)
        {                
            $data [] = ['id' => $value->id, 'value' => $value->name_company];          
        }
        return response($data);
    }

 public function dataTable()
    {

        $ordenes = Order::with(['client.company'], 'user')->get();             
        return dataTables::of($ordenes)
                ->addColumn('id', function ($ordenes){

                    return $ordenes->id;
                })  
                ->addColumn('n°_orden', function ($ordenes){

                    return $ordenes->num;
                })  
                ->addColumn('fecha', function ($ordenes){                 

                    return   '<i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->date->format('d-m-y');

                })
                ->addColumn('cliente', function ($ordenes){

                    return 
                    '<i class="fa fa-industry"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->client->company['name_company']."<br>".
                    '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->client->company['phone_company'];                  

                }) 
                ->addColumn('operario', function ($ordenes){

                    return 
                    '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.' '.$ordenes->user['name'];                    

                })

                ->addColumn('producto', function ($ordenes){

                    return $ordenes->name;                   

                })

                ->addColumn('estado', function ($ordenes){
                    if($ordenes->status !== 'TERMINADO'){
                        return '<span class="label label-danger sm">'.$ordenes->status.'</span>';
                    }else {
                        return '<span class="label label-success sm">'.$ordenes->status.'</span>';
                    }

                })                                              
                ->addColumn('accion', function ($ordenes) {

                    return view('admin.orders.partials._action', [
                        'ordenes' => $ordenes,
                        'url_show' => route('admin.orders.show', $ordenes->id),
                        'url_edit' => route('admin.orders.edit', $ordenes->id),
                        'url_destroy' => route('admin.orders.destroy', $ordenes->id)
                    ]);
                })

                ->addIndexColumn()   
                ->rawColumns(['n°_orden', 'fecha', 'cliente', 'operario', 'producto', 'estado', 'accion'])                
                ->make(true);          
    }
```

formulario:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="color: white; background-color: #5b518b">Clientes</span>
    <input type="text"  id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar cliente">
</div> 
{!! Form::model($order, [
    'route' => $order->exists ? ['admin.orders.update', $order->id] : 'admin.orders.store',   
    'method' => $order->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
]) !!}

<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles del Cliente</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">

                <!-- <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="color: white; background-color: #5b518b">Clientes</span>
                    <input type="text"  id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar cliente">
                </div>  -->

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name_company', 'Nombre') !!}                
                    {!! Form::text('name_company', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_company']) !!}            
                </div>                             

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('phone_company', 'Telefono') !!}                
                    {!! Form::text('phone_company', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_company']) !!}            
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name_client', 'Nombres') !!}            
                    {!! Form::text('name_client', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_client']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('phone_client', 'Telefono') !!}               
                    {!! Form::text('phone_client', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_client']) !!}
                </div>              

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!}             
                    {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email', 'placeholder' => 'Email']) !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalle de la orden</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">


                <div class="form-group">              
                    {!! Form::label('status', 'Estado') !!}                       
                    {!! Form::select('status', $order->getStatus(), null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'status']) !!}            

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name', 'Operario') !!}                
                    {!! Form::select('name', $user, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) !!}            
                </div> 

                <!-- <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name', 'Operario') !!}                
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['name'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) !!}            
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('date', 'Fecha') !!}            
                    {!! Form::text('date', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'date']) !!}
                </div>                 -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles del producto</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">    
            <div class="form-group">              
                    {!! Form::label('num', 'N° orden') !!}                    
                    {!! Form::text('num', null, ['num'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'num']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name', 'Nombre') !!}                
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['name'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) !!}            
                </div>                        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}    
</div>
```

script:

```
$(function(){
 $('#search').autocomplete({           
    source: "{{URL::to('orders/table') }}",
    // source: "{{ route('orders.table') }}",
    // minLength: 2,
    select: function(key,value)
    {
        console.log(value)
    }       

});
});
```

tengo dudas en como estoy procediendo; sera mi script o sera la forma en que cargo el js??.
**Quiero aclarar lo siguiente: tengo mi app.blade(master) y tengo mi vista index.blade en la cual un @include incluyo mi formulario (partials) y por otro lado tengo mi order.js (carpeta public/js) donde tengo todos mis scritps, incluido el autocomplete**

entoces esta seria parte de mi vista index:
aca cargo jquery-ui.min.js

```
@include('admin.orders.partials._modal')



@push('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">   
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
@endpush


@push('scripts')
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/order.js') }}"></script>

    <script>
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('orders.table') }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'n°_orden', name: 'n°_orden'},
                {data: 'fecha', name: 'fecha'},
                {data: 'cliente', name: 'cliente'},
                {data: 'operario', name: 'operario'},
                {data: 'producto', name: 'producto'},
                {data: 'estado', name: 'estado'},               
                {data: 'accion', name: 'accion'}                
            ]
        });  


    </script>
@endpush
```

inspeccione con la consola pero tampoco veo errores 
les agradesco su ayuda estoy trabado con esto!!!

Comment: A como veo tu problema, quieres que el formulario completo se rellene al seleccionar un elemento; de ser así autocomplete no es la herramienta que necesitas, ésta solo te da opciones para que la cantidad de los options de un select disminuyan conforme escribes.

Comment: @Jonathan Orta a lo mejor me expresado mal, pero es así al seleccionar un elemento  se autocomplete los campos de nombre empresa, teléfono, nombre contacto, teléfono contacto y email . El formulario poseer más campos. En este momento estoy tratando de listar por nombre de empresa cosa q no estoy  logrando. (Creo que en el método create() podría pasar lo que estoy haciendo en el metodo search() pero no estoy seguro por eso requiero alguna ayuda

Comment: He visto tutorariales donde empleando el autocomplete se puede realizar lo que necesito pero no estoy lograndolo

Comment: Puedes publicar tu función dataTable de OrderController y publicar tambien lo que te imprima la consola cuando ejecutes la función select()

`select : function(event, ui){ alert( ui.item.value ); }`

Comment: @Jonathan Orta si te fijas agregue el metodo datatable()  no estoy viendo nada en la consola creo q ni se ejecuta el script esa es mi duda. si voy a la ruta veo : ``` [
{
"id": 1,
"value": "Klocko Group"
},
{
"id": 2,
"value": "Jaskolski PLC"
},
{
"id": 3,
"value": "simes"
}
]``` no se si colocar mi script abajo de mi formulario para luego incluirlo en la vista index  o dejarlo donde esta actualmente ahora, que vendria a ser el ``` <script src="{{ asset('js/order.js') }}"></script>```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno voy a dar mi respuesta: Lo que estaba buscando era poder autocompletar campos de un formulario mediante la selección de una opción a través de un input del tipo select. Con la ayuda y paciencia de @porloscerros Ψ pude conseguir lo que necesitaba.
entoces mi controlador OrderController quedo asi:

**->Controlador:** metodo create y show

```
public function create()
    { 
        $order = new Order();  
        $companies = Company::pluck('name_company', 'id');
        $user = User::pluck('name', 'id'); 

        return view('admin.orders.partials.form', compact('order', 'companies', 'user'));
    }

public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $client = Client::with('company')->findOrFail($id);       

        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return $client->toJson();
        }  

        return response()->json(['message' => 'recibimos el request pero no es ajax']);
    }
```

**->Vista blade:** formulario

```
<div class="row">
    {!! Form::model($order, [
        'route' => $order->exists ? ['admin.orders.update', $order->id] : 'admin.orders.store',   
        'method' => $order->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
    ]) !!}
    <div class="col-md-6">    
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles del Cliente</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name_company', 'Nombre empresa') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('name_company',  $companies, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_company', 'placeholder' => 'Selecciona cliente']) !!}
                </div>           

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('phone_company', 'Telefono empresa:') !!}                                                           
                    {!! Form::text('phone_company',  null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_company', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Telefono empresa']) !!}            
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name_client', 'Nombre contacto:') !!}            
                    {!! Form::text('name_client', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_client', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre contacto']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('phone_client', 'Telefono contacto:') !!}               
                    {!! Form::text('phone_client', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_client', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Telefono contacto']) !!}
                </div>              

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('email', 'Email contacto:') !!}             
                    {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Email']) !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalle de la orden</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">              
                    {!! Form::label('status', 'Estado') !!}                       
                    {!! Form::select('status', $order->getStatus(), '[0]', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'status']) !!}                                                 
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name', 'Operario') !!}                
                    {!! Form::select('name', $user, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name', 'placeholder' => 'Selecciona operario']) !!}            
                </div> 

                <!-- Date -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Fecha:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.input group -->
                </div>
              <!-- /.form group -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles del producto</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">    
                <div class="form-group">              
                    {!! Form::label('num', 'N° orden:') !!}                    
                    {!! Form::number('num', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'num']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name_product', 'Nombre producto:') !!}                
                    {!! Form::text('name_product', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_product']) !!}            
                </div>                        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}    
</div>
```

**->Script:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-show', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this),
        url = me.attr('href'),
        title = me.attr('title');



    $('#modal-title').text(title);
    $('#modal-btn-save').removeClass('hide')
    .text(me.hasClass('edit') ? 'Actualizar' : 'Crear');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#modal-body').html(response);

            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                language: 'es'
            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());                  

            var name_companySelect = $('#name_company');
            var phone_company = $('#phone_company');
            var name_client = $('#name_client');
            var phone_client = $('#phone_client');
            var email = $('#email');
            var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');    
            // console.log (name_companySelect);
            name_companySelect.on('change', function() {
                // console.log ('la compañía ha cambiado');
                var id = $(this).val();
                // console.log('id del Company seleccionado: ' + id);
                obtenerDetalleDeCompany(id)

            });

            function obtenerDetalleDeCompany(id) {
                $.ajax({

                    url: '/admin/orders/' + id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {            
                        '_token': csrf_token
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {

                        llenarInputs(response);
                    },
                    error: function () { 
                        console.log(error);
                        alert('Hubo un error obteniendo el detalle de la Compañía!');
                    }
                })
            }

            function llenarInputs(data) {

                phone_company.val(data.company.phone_company);  
                name_client.val(data.name_client);    
                phone_client.val(data.phone_client);    
                email.val(data.email);    
            }
        }
    });

    $('#modal').modal('show');    

});
```

**->Ruta web.php:**

```
Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController', ['as' => 'admin']);
```

Si alguien se encuentra con este tipo de formulario donde se incluye el autocompletado de campos mediante un select esto lo puede ayudar y/o orientar 
saludos!!!